# Monitor user activities and queries in Window server PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, server, monitoring

I am relatively new to managing a PostgreSQL database on a Windows Server, and I am seeking advice on how to monitor user queries and activities in real time in order to effectively manage the database load. Specifically, I am interested in understanding what kind of queries users are running and how much system resources those queries consume.

My goal is to have real-time visibility into user user queries and activities to gain insights into the database load and perform load monitoring on a per-user basis.  I am seeking recommendations for tools or approaches that support real-time monitoring in this context. Ideally, I am looking for tools that can be purchased outright rather than subscribing to a monthly payment plan. But also any other way

As a beginner in this area, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions regarding best practices, recommended tools, or methodologies for achieving real-time monitoring of user queries and activities in PostgreSQL on a Windows Server.

What I have tried: Opmanage, pgAdmin, a5mk2, and pg_stat_activity
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Off-topic: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more: This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers." (and even then, this question needs a lot more details and focus)